# $elemMatch with nested objects (or some other solution)

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of albums, example of album:

```
var album = {
    name: 'album1',
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/12/12' },
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
                {name: 'anotherTask', started: '12/12/10', finished: '12/12/10' }
            ]
        }


    },{
        title: 'track1',
        language: 'en',
    },{
        title: 'track2',
        language: 'es',
    }]
}
```

How can I achieve the following
1) for particular album and track I need to select tasks by name, for example (all 'someTask' for Album1 and track0)

2) The second problem is to select last task in tasks that is not finished.

So, for the first query as a result I need to get:

```
{
    name: 'album1'
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
               {name: 'someTask', started: '12/12/12' },
               {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

For the second query as a result I need to get:

```
{
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

So I want to select only one tasks that satisfy the criteria.
I tried different varians with $elemMath like:

```
tracks: {$elemMatch: {'processing.tasks': {$elemMatch:{name: 'someTask'}}}}
```

But in the result I get all processing.tasks not only tasks with the name 'someTask'.

The second one is more complex, I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: you are trying to do embedded embedded documents... don't think they support that

Comment: It is possible with aggregation framwork, the problem I would like to accomplish it without it if it is possible.

Comment: while it's possible with aggregation framework you may want to reconsider your schema design - when you need to do manipulation of embedded more than one level elements you are going to be very restricted in what you can do.   Have you considered having track be the top level document, and having album be (an indexed) attribute of it?  Then you only have one level of array/embedding.  Another way could be to use an embedded document for tracks rather than an array, but without knowing your whole use case it's hard to say if that will solve all problems without introducing new ones.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky where is the advantages of document oriented db? track is not huge and deeply connected to album. Probably I will consider moving processing away from track record. Thanks, for the tip.